# How to remove a Movie clip from with-init self

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok am trying to remove a movie clip from inside its self. I basically telling a button to play a clip, and at the end of the clip I want it to remove the movie clip. I have tried a few different lines of code but telling me it "1120: Access of undefined property Navi_MC"

```
    root.Main_stage.removeChild(Navi_MC);
```

also

```
    this.Main_stage.removeChild(Navi_MC);
```

Sorry forgot to add the layers are Object(root).Main_stage.Navi_MC

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.parent) { this.parent.removeChild(this); }
```

Should work.

Comment: Not quite. How the Movie clip is set up the code needs to be inside of Navi_MC. The problem i seem to keep having is it only removes half the movie clip where the coding is..

Comment: The answer is good, your setup is bad. Don't have code inside movieClips. If you want code on timeline, make a layer called "Actions" and put code in it's first frame using **Actions** panel (F9). There you can say `removeChild(Navi_MC)` or other stuff like `Navi_MC.gotoAndStop(3);` for frame jumps, or `Navi_MC.Btn_1.alpha = 0.5;` to access a movieClip called Btn_1 and change its transparency... just quick examples of controlling stuff without putting code in the Navi_MC itself.